# java.lang.VerifyError when using S3 connector with Cloud Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to use the [S3 connector](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) with [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) and I am encountering a `java.lang.VerifyError`. This seems to occur on a brand new cluster which I have not modified. Here is an example:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls s3://<my-bucket>/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    ... (truncated stack trace) ...
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

How can I fix this and use the S3 connector with Cloud Dataproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because of an `Apache HttpComponents` version conflict between the S3 conenctor and the [Google BigQuery Hadoop connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector). This is something which should be fixed with the Google BigQuery connector.

In the meantime, you can remove the BigQuery connector as a fix. This will **enable** use of the S3 connector but it will also **disable** use of BigQuery with Cloud Dataproc. To remove the BigQuery connector, use an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/init-actions) when creating a Cloud Dataproc cluster. Here is a sample initialization action which will remove the BigQuery connector.

```
#!/bin/bash
"rm /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/bigquery-connector-0.7.2-hadoop2.jar"
```